# How do I create static dates in golang?

Tags: go, time

I have some golang code that deals with time.Time dates.  I'd like to write some tests that check for specific dates.  How do I do that?

It appears as though the contents of time.Time struct are all private so I can't initialize one directly.  And the only way to create one that I see is to time.Parse it.  But since time.Parse returns two values, (one of which is error), I can't time.Parse in a global var initialization.  I'm stuck with creating my containing structs globally, (which is so-so), but then filling in the time.Time elements later, in init.  This trips several linters who suggest that init is a bad idea, that creating a struct without setting all fields it a bad idea, etc.

Is there a better way to create a constant time.Time?  Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: Have you looked at the `time` package? There arer several ways to produce dates, such as [`time.Date`](https://pkg.go.dev/time#Date) and [`time.Unix`](https://pkg.go.dev/time#Unix).

Comment: "I can't time.Parse in a global var initialization." Why?

Comment: Can't parse because time.Parse returns two values.  No way to check the err code or report errors within the var section.

Comment: time.Unix returns a single value.  That might be a better approach.  Thanks.

Comment: FTR, time.Unix(x, 0).UTC() is needed for consistency.

Answer (score -2):

You can just declare the variable, then use methods to change it:

```
package main

import (
   "fmt"
   "time"
)

func main() {
   var t time.Time
   fmt.Println(t.IsZero()) // true
   fmt.Println(t) // 0001-01-01 00:00:00 +0000 UTC
   t = t.AddDate(1969, 0, 0)
   fmt.Println(t) // 1970-01-01 00:00:00 +0000 UTC
}
```

https://godocs.io/time#Time.AddDate

Comment: There is no main in test files.  I have been doing this with init but it's a nuisance and trips multiple linters as described above.

The time.Unix().UTC() approach seems to accomplish all that I want to accomplish while dodging the linters.